# Including all files in folder in the HDFS path

Tags: java, file, hadoop, path, hdfs

When I Set the following Path:

```
 Path file = new Path("hdfs://hdp2minion1.domain.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/temp_hbase/");
```

It returns a FileNotFoundException (temp_hbase is a folder on HDFS). I want to simply include all the files inside that folder.

Is there any other means to achieve this? Use of wildcards doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `FileSystem`

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs =FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://hostname:portNumber"),configuration);
```

And Than Use.

```
FileStatus[] status=hdfs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://abc.com:9000/my/test/folder"));
```